# Загрузка изображения из url, django

Tags: jquery, python, django

Столкнулся с необходимостью загружать файлы изображений на сервер из *url*.

## views

```
def image_edit(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    data = UserAbout.objects.get(user_id=request.user)
    form = UserAboutImageForm(instance=data)
    args['form'] = form
    if request.POST:
        data = UserAbout.objects.get(user_id=request.user)
        form = UserAboutImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=data)
        args['form'] = form
        if form.is_valid():
            image = form.save(commit=False)
            image.user_id = request.user
            image.save()
            return redirect('/%s/' % request.user)
    return render_to_response('userabout_image_edit.html', args, RequestContext(request))
```

## forms

```
class UserAboutImageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserAbout
        fields = (
            "user_image",
        )

    user_image = forms.ImageField(widget=FileInput(attrs={'onchange': 'file_upload(this)'}))
```

## models

```
class UserAbout(models.Model):
    user_id = models.OneToOneField(User)
    user_image = ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='users')
```

Этот код загружает аватарки на сервер, все работает, но хочется делать так:

Передавать изображение в браузер, обрабатывать при помощи *JQuery*, *JQuery* генерирует ссылку на изображение вида:

```
<a href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAA....(очень длинная ссылка)" download="crop.png">Download</a>
```

Сам *jquery-плагин*: https://github.com/acornejo/jquery-cropbox

Можно ли, вместо скачивания файла по этой ссылке, загрузить его на сервер, например, через форму *Django* (либо как-то еще)?

Answer (score 1):

Ну так сделайте html форму с загрузкой картинки?!
В чем проблема?

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.management_form }}
     <input id="id_image" name="image" type="file" class="form-control">
     <button type="submit" value="Send">Сохранить</button>
</form>
```